# install app without sim card

Tags: google-play-store, bluetooth-pairing

I need a phone to use as a wireless monitor for a go pro camera. The go pro quik software only works on android 9 or later and is only available from google play. As far as I know google play only works on android phones with a working sim card. Does anyone know, if I buy an UNLOCKED Samsung Galaxy S9 and got a temporary sim card could I download the app and would it continue to work after the sim card expired? This is the only thing I will use the phone for. If you know or have any suggestions please let me know.

Comment: Creating a new Google account may need a phone number for account verification, but installing apps from Play Store doesn't need a SIM card.

Comment: There are still Android devices like some tablets that don't have a cellular modem at all, they can only use Wifi and Google Play Store works without any problems on them (of course some apps that require cellular may not be visible in Play Store on such a device)..

Answer (score 2):

You don't a SIM card to access Google Play on an Android device, locked or unlocked, you only need a Google account and Internet access (like WiFi, mobile data isn't required). You should have no issues installing apps from the Google Play store at all.

Comment: That's the problem, it won't let me enter my google account or make a new one with wifi only, I believe I have to have a sim card

Comment: Guess I have never heard of that... Even when setting up a new phone out of the box, you can do it without a SIM card and connect to WiFi and setup a Google account (but not create one on the phone in some cases), and update and install apps... I have done it with tons of phones, both unlocked and carrier locked. Perhaps try a factory reset?